# Upgrading Eclipse SDK for Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse

**EDITED**

Thought I'd follow up a bit more and add the info here (as opposed to adding more comments below).

After installing Galileo and finding it went well and no android problems, I installed Helios.  It too went well and no Android problems (yet).

I did add the necessary lines to the eclipse config ini file to increase Memory size and added Garbage Collection. When I did this to Gannymede, it made a significant speed improvement but, I don't see any effect in either Galileo or Helios.  Makes me think that since they are not natively added for these two versions (at least not for 64-bit Cocoa / Mac), they may not be used. Nonetheless, they seem to have no negative affect. If anyone has knowledge to share on this, I'm all ears...

Thanks

---

I'd like to get opinions on updating Eclipse for Android development.

I currently use Eclipse (Ganymede) 3.4.2. on a Mac (duo core intel)

I've read many posts regarding this and, while there are differing opinions, probably mostly with regard to the interface. I have read about issues with the Android SDK and ADT with Eclipse versions above 3.4.2. but, thus far, all posts seem to be prior to the Android Dev site recommending the following (they previously recommend not using above 3.4):

> - Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) or greater
> - Eclipse JDT plugin (included in most Eclipse IDE packages)
> - If you need to install or update Eclipse, you can download it from
>     http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.
>
>   Several types of Eclipse packages
>     are available for each platform. For
>     developing Android applications, we
>     recommend that you install one of
>     these packages:
>       o Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>       o Eclipse Classic (versions 3.5.1 and higher)
>       o Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Some questions:

1. Is there an advantage in switching from 3.4.2 Ganymede to Classic 3.5.1?
2. Is it worth the trouble?
3. Is anyone having compatibility issues with Android and the ADT? using 3.5.1?

Thanks - any input/recommendations are appreciated...

Comment: I personally have a different eclipse install for each platform I need to work in.  Might be worth it if you're starting Android development from scratch

Comment: Thanks. I use Netbeans for pure java and eclipse for only android. I previously installed another eclipse and had nothing but cross-platform version trouble so, I stay with only one eclipse version.

Comment: I've read somewhere that 3.6 has problems for sure with ADT

Comment: I use 3.6. The problem is the code complete. You have to download the android source to get code complete to not be really slow.

Comment: Thanks, all... Been reading a bit more since posting this and haven't seen anything positive about upgrading from Ganymede (with respect to Android). I'm thinking I'll stick with Ganymede until an overwhelming number of folks have good things to say about upgrades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't encounter noticeable problems with Helios (3.6.1). We bundle Helios (Classic more or less) and a bunch of plugins we write together with ADT to form MOTODEV Studio. As a general rule, the integration and support for Android have gotten better with each Eclipse release.  I don't believe the Android team tests against Ganymede any longer, so at the very least I'd suggest moving to Galileo.

Comment: thanks. Now that my apps are revised and on the Market, I can take a break and spend time upgrading to Galileo (and will cross my fingers). I used the Motodev front-end for awhile but went back to eclipse.

Comment: I installed Galileo and all seems well. I have a question you may be able to answer: I previously configured eclispe ini file to increase the memory size and enable garbage collection but, I don't see these lines the ini for Galileo.  I suppose I can try adding them and see what happerns. What is the default for this with Galileo and your opinion on this?  Thanks Oh, uisng mac in 64-bit mode and installed the cocoa 64 bit version of eclipse.

Comment: @headscratch We'd like to see you as a user again someday, but if you're happy with Eclipse, then we're happy too. ;-)

Comment: @headscratch I find that the default values for start and max are rather conservative.  It's good to strike a balance between the minimal and maximal user, but I think the default values are rooted in the days when a single core 1.2mhz CPU with 1 GB of RAM was the typical engineer's desktop. I don't think it matters if you put them in eclipse.ini after -vmargs or on your launch script on MacOS.